# Expanding events from the list in a JSON object inside the Elastic Search pipeline and inserting them as a separate document in the elastic index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Hello experts in Elastic Search

We need to customize our **Elastic Ingest Pipeline**.

We are facing a challenge and want to know if there is a way of expanding events from the list in a JSON object inside the **ingest pipeline** and inserting them as a separate document in the elastic index.

Giving the following Input inside the elastic:

```
{"@timestamp": "2022-06-16T04:06:03.064Z", "message": "{ "name":"name #1", "logEvents":[{"key": "value #1"},{"key": "value #2"}]}"}
{"@timestamp": "2022-06-16T04:06:13.888Z", "message": "{ "name":"name #2", "logEvents":[{"key": "value #3"},{"key": "value #4"}]}"}
```

We want to iterate for each event inside the list of logEvents, be able to customize the data, and insert each event as an individual document inside elastic.

This is the Output we want to have after passing throw the pipeline processors:

```
{"@timestamp": "2022-06-16T04:06:21.105Z", "message": "{"name":"name #1", "key": "value #1"}"}
{"@timestamp": "2022-06-16T04:06:27.204Z", "message": "{"name":"name #1", "key": "value #2"}"}
{"@timestamp": "2022-06-16T04:06:31.154Z", "message": "{"name":"name #2", "key": "value #3"}"}
{"@timestamp": "2022-06-16T04:06:36.189Z", "message": "{"name":"name #2", "key": "value #4"}"}
```

Essentially we want to achieve this functionality inside Elastic without using Lambda.
https://github.com/elastic/elastic-serverless-forwarder/blob/main/docs/README-AWS.md#expanding-events-from-list-in-json-object

Is that possible?

Thank You in advanced
I appreciate your help and Dedication.

Answer (score 0):

The Logstash [`split` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html) should work for your case (after decoding the JSON message inside the `message` field):

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"        
  }
  split {
    field => "logEvents"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Val. We need to customize our Elastic Ingest Pipeline not Logstash

Comment: The Elasticsearch ingest pipeline processes one document at a time and cannot split one document into multiple ones